# Serial port communication in VC++

Tags: visual-c++, com, types, serial-port

when reading data through serial port

```
VARIANT data;
BSTR k;
if(m_mscom.GetCommEvent() == 2)
{
    data = m_mscom.GetInput();      
    k = data.bstrVal;
    }
```

What is `BSTR k;` and
what do you mean `k=data.bstrVal`? What is `bstrVal`?

Answer (score 1):

[BSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221069.aspx) and [VARIANT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221627.aspx) are data types used in COM. Actually, VARIANT is a container that may hold any COM data type.

In your case, GetInput() returns VARIANT containing a buffer as BSTR, so bstrVal has to be used to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

BSTR is a pointer to unicode character(just character type that can hold unicode character).
data.bstrVal converts variant to BSTR.